# consulta con un datagridview C#

Tags: c#

tengo un datagrid view donde se carga informacion de un documento excel y hasta ahi funciona bien, ahora necesito que tome todos los datos de la columna 2 para hacer una consulta a la base de datos con esa informacion para hacer una especie de autocomplementacion pero no logro hacer que tome los valores del datagrid

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Class1 objeto = new Class1();
        public Form1()
        {
            //Insertar.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static class compartirVariable
        {
            public static String variable;
        }

        private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Insertar.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }

        private void Btncerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //volver al inicio de sesion
            Dispose();
            login AbrirVentana = new login();
            this.Hide();
            AbrirVentana.Show();
        }



        private void btncargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string hoja = "libro1";    //constante de el numero de la hoja
            string direccion = "1";        //variable receptora de la direccion del documento
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    direccion = openfile1.FileName;
                }
                {
                    string pathconn = "Provider = Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" + direccion + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR= yes;\";"; //conexion concatenando la variable con la direccion del archivo excel
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathconn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + hoja + "$]", conn); //consulta concatenando la constante con el nombre de la hoja
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    Insertar.DataSource = dt;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception Error){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Error.Message);
            }

        }

        private void btnlimpiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 172.29.110.115; Initial Catalog =" + compartirVariable.variable + "; User ID = sa ; Password = complementos");

            //SqlCommand autocomplementar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM y_personal_contratos where contrato =  '" + contrato + '"', conexion);

            SqlCommand autocomplementar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM y_personal_contratos where contrato = @contrato", conexion);

            conexion.Open();

            try
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Insertar.Rows)
                {
                    autocomplementar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrato", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value));
                    autocomplementar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception Error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Error.Message);
            }
            //string contrato = Insertar.RowCount();
            dgvprueba.DataSource = autocomplementar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) cambia la forma de como obtienes el dato en cada recorrido del datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Esta linea no te sirve

```
Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value)
```

Deberia ser algo como esto

```
Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Controls[0].Value)
```

Simplemente crea un punto de interrupcion en esta linea y luego examina el row para llegar al control que alberga el value que quieres obtener, con un findcontrol sabiendo id tambien puedes llegar.

Answer (score 0):

Hola me parece q seria mejor recorrer el dt asi:

```
    try
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in Insertar.Rows)
            {

                string midato = row[1].ToString();
                autocomplementar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrato", midato);
                autocomplementar.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```